# Online Users List

Tags: feature-request

What If we have something like online users list .

So on helping with the problems/Questions, for discussions we could invite to chat from the posting area . so this online list users can give us a confirmation that the other end user  is online or offline .so if he is online we can send him a discussion invite on his issue/problem and we can improve the time of issue solving .

i thinks its also a good idea .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meh, you can already do this.

In your scenario, if you want to check whether a user is online, you can just pootle over to their profile page and look at the "Last Seen" value. If they're active and on the site, it'll tell you clearly.

And in terms of contacting them, you can just leave a comment on their question or (and I think this works) write @their_username in chat and they'll get a notification at the top of their screen.

I don't see the utility in adding a fat list of users who are currently online (like the forums do). It doesn't really *do* anything for the user experience.

Comment: It also creates an additional privacy concern.